# Asynchronous loading JavaScript functions.

Tags: javascript, performance, requirejs, commonjs

I am building a framework in which I have merged all JavaScript files into one file (minify).

Example:

```
   function A() {} function B() {}
```

Through minified file i want to load function asynchronous and remove from HTML when its work is done.

Example: load function A when it is required but not function B.

I have seen one framework Require.js but in that it loads JavaScript file asynchronous based on requirement.

Is there any framework which loads JavaScript functions on demand which are defined in same js file.

Comment: Loading individual functions is actually an anti-optimization. You're optimizing memory footprint and compilation time (which are usually not serious bottlenecks) by sacrificing network load (each function causes the browser to open another socket to the server) which is the main bottleneck for web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downside to concatenation is you get less fine-grained control over what you are including on a given page load. The solution to this is, rather than creating one concatenated file, create *layers* of functionality that can be included a little more modularly. Thus you don't need all your JS on a page that may only use a few specific functions. This can actually be a win in speed as well, since having just one JS file might not take advantage of the browsers 6 concurrent connections. Moreover, once SPDY is fully adopted, one large file will actually be less performant than more smaller ones (since connections can be reused). Minification will still be important, however.

All that said, it seems you are asking for something a little difficult to pull off. When a browser loads a script, it gets parsed and executed immediately. You can't load the file then... only load part of the file. By concatenating, you are restricting yourself to that large payload.

It is possible to delay execution by wrapping a script in a block comment, then accessing it from the script node and `eval()`ing it... but that doesn't seem like what you are asking. It can be a useful strategy, though, if you want to preload modules without locking the UI.

Comment: I got a solution in your answer, by minify all classes separately in different files, I can use requirejs on that.

Doing this code will also be minified and I can load classes based on demand by using require js.

Thanks a lot Wyatt for your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah minification is just reducing the bytes getting sent over the wire so no matter how many files you have, you'll get a speed boost. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how javascript works. When the function's source file is loaded, the function is available in memory. Since the language is interpreted, the functions that are defined would be loaded as soon as the source file was read by the browser.

Your best bet is to use Require.js or something similar if you want to have explicit dependency chains.